# CKeditor 4 remove class attribute when changing format tag

Tags: ckeditor4.x

When using the Custom Text Format Definition (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/format.html) it is possible to add attributes to tag definition like this :

```
config.format_tags = 'p;h1';
config.format_p = { element: 'p'};
config.format_h1 = { element: 'h1', attributes: { 'class': 'lorem-ipsum' } };
```

My issue is that when applying `h1` from the dropdown, the `lorem-ipsum` class is added, OK, but when going back to `p`the `lorem-ipsum` class is not deleted. I tried with `attributes: false`, `attributes: null`, `attributes: {}` but nothing make them disapear when switching between tags.

The issue is visible on the CKEDITOR demo : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/format.html under the Custom Text Format Definition title. When change the tags their class stays.

So how to erase classes when change tag from the format dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works (I checked it in ver. 4.6.2):

```
config.format_p = { element : 'p', attributes: {'class' : ''} };
```

In this case if you switch to `p` the attribute disappears.